# Nginx subdirectory root with PHP

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I'm running nginx in a docker container. I want to have a subdirectory `/web/` to access my personal files and projects. It should also support php.

Below is what I'm running with but `domain-a.com/web` keeps resulting in a 404. PHP is confirmed working since the same php block works on a subdomain but directly in a `server{}` block.

```
http {

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        server_name domain-a.com domain-b.com;

        # Mime types
        include /etc/nginx/confs/mime.types;

        # SSL
        include /etc/nginx/confs/nginx-ssl.conf;

        # Proxy to organizr
        # This works
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://organizr/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # HTTP 1.1 support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
        }

        # Root folder for my personal files/projects
        # Doesn't work
        location /web {
            index index.php index.html;
            root /etc/nginx/www;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your files also in a sub-directory, i.e. `/etc/nginx/www/web/`?

Comment: @RichardSmith No, they are in `/etc/nginx/www/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your files are in `/etc/nginx/www` you will need to use an `alias` directive, rather than a `root` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /web {
    index index.php index.html;
    alias /etc/nginx/www;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /web/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Use `$request_filename` to obtain the correct path to the aliased file. Avoid `try_files` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer. Worked straight away.

Comment: Your notice saved my time. Thank you!