# ubuntu 16.04 nginx change phpmyadmin url not working

Tags: nginx

```
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS Xenial 4.18.8-x86_64-linode117
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
php v7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                root /usr/share/;
        }
}
```

No symlink at `/var/www/html`
**Worx well....**

But I can't seem to figure out how to change `phpmyadmin` url.
Tried creating a symlink `whatever ->/usr/share/phpmyadmin` or `whatever ->/usr/share/phpmyadmin/` under `/var/www/html`does not work,
Even if I change `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to:

```
location /whatever {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
```

Created a symlink as mentioned above, restarted both `nginx` & `php7.0-fpm` still the new URL tried to download the page...

Looked up different resources on the net but they dont help:
[digitalocean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)
[devanswers guide](https://devanswers.co/installing-phpmyadmin-nginx-ubuntu-16-04-17-04/)
As well as other here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) but couldn't find a solution.
Ideas??

**UPDATE**
By [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)'s remark

```
location /whatever {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /phpmyadmin/index.php last; }
    # Secure phpMyAdmin Instance
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.your_pass_file;
    client_max_body_size 68M;

    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to use `alias` instead of `root`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319049/nginx-subdirectory-root-with-php/47332159#47332159) for an example.

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated the question with the modified server block still `nginx` gives `403 Forbidden`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
location ^~ /whatever {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /whatever/index.php last; }
    # Secure phpMyAdmin Instance
    auth_basic "Admin Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.your_pass_file;
    client_max_body_size 68M;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

You need to use `/whatever/index.php` in the `rewrite` statement. The nested location blocks only need to match the end of the URI. The `^~` modifier avoids conflicts with other regular expression `location` blocks at the `server` block level. Use `$request_filename` in the SCRIPT_FILENAME. Your last nested `location` block appears to perform no function.

Avoid `try_files` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: So far the only answer I found that still works. Kudos.